# How do I find the value of AM_MAKEFLAGS?

Tags: linux, makefile, automake

I am trying to build a software package I am unfamiliar with, and it uses automake, which I am also unfamiliar with.  The various Makefiles have the macro $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) all over the place.  I need to know what's in this macro.  I have grepped and grepped and cannot find where it is defined.  Does this mean AM_MAKEFLAGS is blank?  Or does automake typicall put it somewhere I would never think to look?  Bottom line: If I can't find it defined anywhere, how do I know what's in it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When invoking `make`, you can use the command-line parameter `-p` or `--print-data-base` to have it print the values of all rules and variables it encounters. Redirecting the output to a file and searching for `AM_MAKEFLAGS` in that file will show you whether the variable is defined and if so, what its value is. See section [9.7 Summary of Options](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html#Options-Summary) for some extra information.

Comment: Ah yes, "-p".  Forgot.  Thanks for your patience with a novice's question.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that it is rarely necessary nor desirable to look at either the `Makefile.in` generated by automake, or the `Makefile` built by configure (via config.status) from the `Makefile.in` template.  These are not intended form human consumption.  Reading them is similar to looking at the machine code generated by the compiler rather than the original source code.

`AM_MAKEFLAGS` is a mechanism through which the package maintainer can essentially append text to `MAKEFLAGS`.  Every invocation of `make` will be called with `AM_MAKEFLAGS` as an argument.  It is (very) often left undefined, and can be ignored.  If the maintainer did choose to define it, the definition would be in `Makefile.am`, and the line providing the definition would simply be copied verbatim into `Makefile.in` by automake.